# Getting Failed ionic-v1 build **not supported** error in firebase?

Tags: javascript

hope you can help me, in this case I'am trying to generate an apikey for my proyect in ionic v1, but it is being kind of impossible since I get this error during the process. Any possible solution for this?

Comment: I think we'll need some code, some configuration, something, before we're able to answer;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That actually means that you need to upgrade your app's code because is deprecated for this service, possible solutions are look for another cloud messaging service that still supports that framework (consider most of them are paid), or just get started with ionic 3 in order to have complete disposition of actual methods, plugins and standar services, including firebase.